# Show different enums to choose from based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

is there a way that for a table to be able to choose a value in a column based on another column?
For example,let's say I have Player.ToyType Player.ToySubType where

```
enum ToyType {
    Cars
    Dolls
}
```

I want that,if Player.ToyType is Cars, then Player.ToySubType would be another enum like

> enum CarSubType {
>       Truck
>       Electrical }

and if ToyType is Dolls then I would have to choose from

> enum DollsSubType {    Blonde    Brunette }

Answer (score 0):

You can add two columns in your table, one is Type for the ToyType enum, and the other is SubType for the SubTypes of the corresponding ToyType.

Comment: Well,yes,but I don't want to have ALL subtypes (including cars and dolls) in one column, I want to show them depending on what value is ToyType,as I stated above

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are trying to achieve here, Data storage and presentation layers are mostly independent.

Comment: basically what I want to do is if(type == dolls) { column = doll type } if (type == cars) { column = cars type } . You are telling me it's impossible to do this thing? and I have to put all types of cars and dolls into one column?